# Extraer texto de cadena SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Tengo una base de datos la cual almacena el JSON de los errores de una web, de esta manera:

```
    { 
    "message": "We're very sorry, but an unhandled exception has occurred!",   
    "apiId": "99999",   
    "Date": "2022-03-30T21:21:42.371Z" 
    }
```

Pero solo quiero extraer del string lo que tenga "message".
He intentado esto pero nose como indicarle que termine hasta que encuetre las siguientes comillas "

```
    declare @cadenaDeTexto varchar(1000)
    set @cadenaDeTexto = '{   "message": "We're very sorry, but an unhandled exception has occurred!",   "apiId": "9999",   "Date": "2022-03-16T17:24:57.092Z" }'

    select substring(@cadenaDeTexto,17,1000) as messageError
```

Comment: Te faltó indicar la consulta que estás usando y la versión de MSSQL que usas

Comment: @Alfabravo ya he editado la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server tiene lógica para manipular JSON de forma nativa. Puedes usar `JSON_VALUE` para leer tu JSON y extraer el valor que necesitas (comenté tu select y puse uno que es el que sugiero que uses):

```
declare @cadenaDeTexto varchar(1000)
set @cadenaDeTexto = '{   "message": "We''re very sorry, but an unhandled exception has occurred!",   "apiId": "9999",   "Date": "2022-03-16T17:24:57.092Z" }';
-- select substring(@cadenaDeTexto,17,1000) as messageError;

select JSON_VALUE(@cadenaDeTexto, '$.message') as actualMessage;
```

Como ves, el carácter especial `'` en el mensaje toca escaparlo para que se lea como un JSON válido (con otro `'` lo escapamos).

La otra recomendación es comenzar siempre por la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). Suele ser útil!

**Edito:** Si tienes esos líos de formato, yo no daría tantas vueltas. Si haces `JSON_VALUE` de un elemento que no está en el JSON, te va a devolver `NULL`. Así pues, puedes recibir

```
declare @cadenaDeTexto varchar(1000)
declare @cadenaDeTexto2 varchar(1000)
declare @msg1 varchar(1000), @msg2 varchar(1000)


set @cadenaDeTexto = '{   "message": "We''re very sorry, but an unhandled exception has occurred!",   "apiId": "9999",   "Date": "2022-03-16T17:24:57.092Z" }';
set @cadenaDeTexto2 = '{   "msg": "We''re really sorry!",   "apiId": "9999",   "Date": "2022-03-16T17:24:57.092Z" }';

select @msg1 = JSON_VALUE(@cadenaDeTexto, '$.message');
select @msg2 = JSON_VALUE(@cadenaDeTexto, '$.msg');
```

Y después jugar con validaciones sobre msg1 y msg2 para ver cuál NO es nulo y usarlo, etc.

Comment: Wow! Increíble que la solución fuera tan sencilla. Buena respuesta!

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez una o dos versiones hacia atrás, hacer eso mismo habría sido MUY aburrido.

Comment: @Huntzberger dejé alguna idea sobre por dónde podría ir la cosa en tu escenario